# Не получается отправить запрос на сайт

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
url: "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London",
success: function (data) {
    var weather = { main: data.main, name: data.name, weather:
        data.weather[0], wind: data.wind};
        console.log(weather);
}
});
```

Ошибка:

> GET http://localhost:8080/api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q= 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Правильный запрос:
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=

Comment: По-моему кроссдоменный аякс в таком виде запрещен... Нужно использовать jsonp-тип или другие ухищрения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну во-первых адрес localhost никак не может быть указан.
https://www.openweathermap.org/api

Попробуйте так: https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=<ключ, который получаете в личном кабинете>[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня appid не указан, поэтому и ошибка)